# How to efficiently represent any possible mutations to a string of a given length?

Tags: formal-languages, data-compression

I'm trying to find a "language" or a way to express any change that has occurred to a string.

I'm given two strings; a seed string and a new string of the same length that came from it. I'm trying to find the "algorithm" or causes that made the second string what it is.

Now, my current thinking is to come up with a "master list of steps" that I could then experiment with in different combinations in order to determine the correct algorithm to go from the first string to the second. This "master list" is potentially infinite, but I'm hoping to find a subset of steps that, taken in combination could describe any possible change to any possible string.

Below I have an example of a string and and altered string. I've come up with two steps that can be combined in an algorithm that, taken together, explain how it changed. That is to say given the original string, I can reproduce the mutated string by applying both steps to the original string:

Original String

A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q

Mutated String:

A   B   F   D   E   G   H   N   I   J   K   M   C   L   O   P   Q

The first step could be to express simply which indices changed. Something perhaps like this: _ _ X _ _ X X X _ _ _ X X X _ _ _

The second step could be to express which indices will adopt the values of other indices in the string. For example: index 2 adopts index 5's value, index 5 adopts 6, 6 gets 7, 7 gets 13, 13 gets 11, 11 gets 12, and 12 gets 2 for example. That might be expressed by something like this: _ _ 5 _ _ 6 7 (13) _ _ _  (12) 2 (11) _ _ _

The steps above could be done in any order but must both be applied to the seed string. The first step tells us which letter have and have not changed, and the second step tells us what they changed into.

These steps make up an algorithm which is sufficient to describe how this string has changed but can't describe strings that introduce new letters or have other types of changes, thus I'll need more possible types of steps to express different kinds of changes.

Now I suppose this is a type of compression. idk. But is making a myriad of steps, and then combining them in different ways the appropriate way to do this? Or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

It seems intuitive to me that if I'm going to receive many strings like the one above that change in many different ways that I can predict yet then in order to express those changes succinctly I should create a bunch of these types of "steps" that I can put together as needed to create algorithms for expressing such change. Is my intuition correct? What kinds of problems is this related to? I don't know the correct vocabulary to use.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking; I'm not sure what you are looking for.  I'm not sure what you mean by a "language".  What are you trying to accomplish?  If I gave an answer, what criteria would you use to evaluate it?  *"Is making a myriad of rules the appropriate way to do this?"* - do what?  I can't tell what your ultimate purpose is.  What does it mean to "express"/"explain" any change?  [Are you looking for a transducer? for edit distance? for sequence alignment algorithms?]

Comment: ok, I'm sorry for the vagaries of my original question, I've changed it to try to be more direct, does that help?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do delta compression on strings.  There are several variants of **levenshtein distance** that may provide some insights.

Comment: Yes, putting it in steps will help. Please clear obsolete comments. First step will be to check what stays in order, second to check what changed place, but the next is not obvious yet - I hope you do not have infinite number of rules for changing. In this part you want to find what rules were used to give you the string? Compress the differences? Could you give minimal working example of your objective? Some example rules, one seed and string, which will fully show what is needed?